# Cannot create rest web services in Oracle APEX 20.2

Tags: rest, web-services, http-error, oracle-apex-20.2

I am new to Oracle APEX. i am trying to create the rest web services from Oracle APEX 20.2 application, but i am facing HTTP failure error which is in the screenshot

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't know anything about apex, but doesn't the error say that you're not connecting from an allowed network address?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an ACL to APEX. Run the select statement to verify the username that need permissions and then create the acl to that user.

```
-- Verify the APEX Schema
SELECT TABLE_OWNER FROM all_synonyms
WHERE SYNONYM_NAME = 'WWV_FLOW' and OWNER = 'PUBLIC'


-- Execute as sysdba
DECLARE
  l_acl       VARCHAR2(100) := 'aclname.xml';
  l_desc      VARCHAR2(100) := 'description';
  l_principal VARCHAR2(30)  := 'APEX_200200'; -- EXAMPLE APEX 20.2
  l_host      VARCHAR2(100) := 'localhost'; --hostname
BEGIN
  dbms_network_acl_admin.create_acl(l_acl, l_desc, l_principal, TRUE, 'connect');
  dbms_network_acl_admin.add_privilege(l_acl, l_principal, TRUE, 'resolve');
  dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_acl(l_acl, l_host);
 
  COMMIT;
END;
```